# Proper way to create an instance variable using jQuery UI Widget Factory

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I'm using the jQuery UI widget factory.

```
$.widget("myPlugin" , {

    options: {
    },

    _create: function() {
    },

    instanceVar: "huzzah!"

});
```

On testing, it looks as though instanceVar is actually part of the prototype.  So it is the same across all instances of the plugin.

I can fix this by putting instanceVar into options, like so:

```
$.widget("myPlugin" , {

    options: {
        instanceVar: "huzzah!"
    },

    _create: function() {
    },

});
```

However that seems odd, as instanceVar is just an internal variable for use by the plugin -- not something the user of the plugin should be able to change.

Is there another (better) way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can store private data on the instance itself, for example, inside the _create, you should be able to do `this.instanceVar = "huzzah!"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can store private data on the instance itself, for example, inside the `_create`, you should be able to do `this.instanceVar = "huzzah!"`

```
$.widget("ui.myPlugin", {

    options: {
        foo: "foo"
    },

    _create: function() {
        this.instanceVar = "huzzah!"
    },

    _setOption: function() {
        this.instanceVar = "worky!";
    },

    destroy: function() {
        console.log(this.instanceVar);  
    }

});

$(document).myPlugin().myPlugin("option","foo","bar").myPlugin("destroy"); // "worky"

$("body").myPlugin().myPlugin("destroy"); // "huzzah!
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PGUqr/

Comment: You can also declare a private instance variable just like you would a function by using the underscore prefix as a convention.  _instanceVar: undefined,

Comment: It should be noted that using the underscore prefix does not actually prevent access to such 'private' members and methods.  You can still access them via $('#myElement').data('pluginName')._foo.  What adding the underscore does is to omit that function from being available via the usual way of calling methods on the widget: $('#myElement').pluginName('somePublicFunction').  Once you have a reference to the widget instance you have full access to everything regardless of whether it has a leading underscore.

Comment: Note also that although the `option` member doesn't have an underscore, the docs indicate access to its contents via the .option() method: https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-option